# How to remove drop shadow in basic links in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

```
<div data-role="page" style="background:#000">
    <a href="http://google.com">test</a>
</div>
```

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/KCqqN/

Jquery Mobile appears to add a white color drop shadow, how to get rid of that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your stylesheet (make sure it is below the jQuery mobile stylesheet)

Simply set the text-shadow yourself, to whatever you want.

`.ui-body-c, .ui-overlay-c { text-shadow:0 0 0; }`

In the jsFiddle it loads the jquery mobile css afterwards, so if you throw an additional tag in there (or use !important, better not to though) it'll trump it.

`body .ui-body-c, body .ui-overlay-c { text-shadow:0 0 0; } // more specificity`

http://jsfiddle.net/KCqqN/2/

Answer (score 2):

Very simple!

add code below before everything in your CSS:

```
* {
    text-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped! This shadow thingy in JQuery Mobile is so annoying, they should not set it by default!

Comment: You are welcome and I'm glad that line of code helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting your own link css in the head tag, then adding a "text-shadow= none !important;" tag to make sure you override whatever jquery does. And because !important overrides browser accessibility setting, I would also suggest making your text very dark and big and background very light or vice versa so as not to annoy your colorblind/vision-impaired users whose accessibility settings won't work